# Perl debugging: Variable being set to `1` is set to `undef` unexpectedly

Tags: perl, debugging, undef

Note: Please read carefully; it's odd (unless I have tomatoes on my eyes)

I was changing a program of mine when it suddenly stopped to work as intended, and I failed to find the reason.
Eventually I found it; please consider this Perl debugger session extract (Perl 5.18.2):

```perl
  DB<8> x $result
0  undef
  DB<9> c
main::receive_message(./syslogd.pl:1555):
1555:           $result = 1;
  DB<9> x $result
0  ARRAY(0x375cdb0)
   0  IO::Socket::INET=GLOB(0x2f8aa20)
      -> *Symbol::GEN3
            FileHandle({*Symbol::GEN3}) => fileno(6)
   1  SocketAddress=ARRAY(0x375d188)
      0  'v04:36766'
      1  'v04'
      2  36766
      3  ''
   2  '<22>May 23 10:22:07 v04 postfix/cleanup[22002]: F26AB68046: message-id=<1653294126.782e1e75c78c74d3@v04>'
  DB<10> n
main::receive_message(./syslogd.pl:1561):
1561:       $lc->verbose(3, "$me: returning " . Class::_format_undef($result));
  DB<10> x $result
0  undef
```

So in line 1555 `$result` will be set to `1` (inside an `if`-`else` block).
Before `$result` is an `ARRAY` ref (as seeen).
However after the line was executed (by `n`), the value of `$result` is `undef`, not `1` (right after the `if`-`else` block, thus a few lines later).

As the result will be returned, the caller sees the wrong result value and fails.

Unfortunately either me or Perl is heavily confused.
Who can explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tomatoes fell of my eyes!
(I'm providing this answer instead of deleting the question just in case someone will ever see a similar problem)

The code basically was:

```perl
sub receive_message($$$$;$)
{
    #...
    my $result;
    my $lc = $err_mh->log_config();

    if (defined(my $result = $lsa->receive(undef, MAXLEN, $flags))) {
        #...
        $result = 1;   # line 1555
    } else {
        #...
    }
    $lc->verbose(3, "$me: returning " . Class::_format_undef($result)); # line 1561
    return $result;
}
```

So the error was: "a `my` too much" (in the `if`).